# WSO2 version 2 docker files

Tags: docker, wso2, dockerfile, wso2-api-manager

we want to setup WSO2 Api Manager in order to run as a docker container. Unfortunately the present version on github (https://github.com/wso2/dockerfiles) seems to be outdated (version 1.2.1).

Manually modifying the dockerfiles to be able to run a version 2 wso2 in docker ended up in a broken swagger inside of wso2 (using docker ips instead of public ips, unable to test api, etc etc) and required a number of modifications in order to get a running wso2 instance. I consider this patchery as unclean.

So here is my question: Are there version2 docker files out? Did anybody run them and was able to test the APIs with the built in swagger?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WSO2 has done some changes to the dockerfiles and you can find the latest dockerfiles for API Manager in [[1]](https://github.com/wso2/docker-apim).

Please refer the article [[2]](https://www.yenlo.com/blog/wso2-api-manager-dockerized) to get more information about how you can run.